# Is there a fix for my Thinkpad laptop mouse cursor from locking/freezing?

Tags: mouse, freeze, thinkpad

On my Thinkpad L420 laptop intel 2nd gen graphics i5 processor the mouse cursor freezes and locks up every so often. Sometimes it's as often as once every few minutes.  The mouse cursor will freeze on the screen and I have to wait a few seconds (sometimes 5+) for it to unfreeze.

It's a big problem and it happens only on Ubuntu. It has been there in 11.10, 11.04, 10.04 (possibly 10.04 not definite).

It has to be related to the Thinkpad because I never had this problem on a desktop, even with a wireless mouse.

If I could fix this, I could have Ubuntu up and running but for now I give booting to Ubuntu.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).